# How to remove double-quotes in jq output for parsing json files in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, jq

I'm using jq to parse a JSON file as shown [here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html#comment-13001). However, the results for string values contain the "double-quotes" as expected, as shown below:

```
$ cat json.txt | jq '.name'
"Google"
```

How can I pipe this into another command to remove the ""? so I get

```
$ cat json.txt | jq '.name' | some_other_command
Google
```

What `some_other_command` can I use?

Comment: FYI, `cat foo | bar` is significantly less efficient than `bar <foo` or its equivalent `<foo bar`, *especially* if `bar` is a program like `sort` that can parallelize its operations when given a seekable file descriptor as opposed to a FIFO (which can only be read once front-to-back). It both means more startup overhead (invoking `/bin/cat`), and more context switches between userspace and kernel (each piece of content going through a `read()` within `cat`, then a `write()` to a FIFO in `cat`, and then a `read()` inside your destination program, instead of skipping to that last step directly).

Comment: Another example of a case where the difference is a big one is `cat foo | wc -c`, vs `wc -c <foo` -- in the latter case it can just do two syscalls, `seek()` and `tell()`, to get the exact size of the file now matter how long it is; in the former, it needs to read to the end, even if that's gigabytes of content, because only `cat` has direct access to the original file, and `wc` has no way to request metadata on it.

Comment: That is some really good info. Where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 1246, accepted):

Use the `-r` (or `--raw-output`) option to emit raw strings as output:

```
jq -r '.name' <json.txt
```

Comment: If you want to strip the quotes, just pipe the output from this command to `tr -d '"'`.

Comment: @hd1, that's only true if there aren't literal quotes. If someone's name is `"Mack \"The Knife\" Smith"`, you want it to change to `Mack "The Knife" Smith`, not `Mack The Knife Smith`.

Comment: The first comment says they " just want to strip the quotes", which I did. Corner cases like yours don't come into the discussion

Comment: Whether any given corner case is safe to ignore needs to be an explicit, case-by-case design consideration as a rule. Otherwise you end up in the world we live in, where software is riddled with bugs because the design didn't consider the full scope of possible inputs. Which is to say -- unless someone lays out _as a requirement_ that `"` can never exist as literal data as opposed to syntax, it's irresponsible to assume such to be the case. (I work in security, and see sooo many issues misclassified as "input validation" failures when they're really failure to design for the full input domain)

Comment: jq takes a filename so no need to pipe or redirect the file contents `jq -r '.name' json.txt` works just fine

Comment: @grim_i_am: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368663/72707) to see where that idiom comes from.

Comment: @grim_i_am that doesn't seem to work, jq returns: "jq: error: Could not open file json.txt: No such file or directory". The carrot works fine.

Comment: Isn't that arrow pointing the wrong way for this purpose? Works for me pointing to the filename.

Comment: @ucbpaladin, `<json.txt` _reads from_ the file `json.txt`, whereas `>json.txt` _empties the file `json.txt` and then writes to it_. The OP here is using `cat json.txt`, so they want to _read from_ the file, so `<` is correct.

Answer (score 62):

So for a file containing just `{"name": "Google"}` then yes

```
sample='{"name":"Google"}'
echo $sample| jq '.name'

"Google"
```

using `--raw-output` helps

```
echo $sample| jq --raw-output '.name'

Google
```

But I stumbled upon this question because I was using `--raw-output` on a json array like this

```
sample='[{"name":"Yahoo"},{"name":"Google"}]'
echo $sample | jq --raw-output 'map(.name)'

[
  "Yahoo",
  "Google"
]
```

And I didn't understand why the quotes remained. I came across [this post](https://www.starkandwayne.com/blog/bash-for-loop-over-json-array-using-jq/), and now I know adding `| .[]` does the trick!

```
echo $sample | jq --raw-output 'map(.name)| .[]'

Yahoo
Google
```

Comment: Note that `echo $sample` is itself buggy. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) -- always `echo "$sample"`, with the quotes; or, even better, `printf '%s\n' "$sample"`