# Control characters in jq parsed JSON

Tags: json, bash, shell, ksh, jq

I am writing a KSH shell script. It reads from a JSON file, which contains control characters like `\n`, `\r` and `\t` in place of actual newline characters or tabs (so the control characters are being read as actual strings). I am using `jq` to parse the stuff I want from this JSON file, and appending it to a text file. This text file also ends up having the strings like `\n`, `\t` instead of newline, tabs, etc. I want the text file to have actual meaning of these control characters.

For example, for the string `"I\nam\na\ngood\nboy"`, I want my file to have:

```
I
am
a
good
boy
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this in a shell script?

Note: I am writing in KSH, but answers in bash etc. would be acceptable.

Comment: How to change `"I\nam\na\ngood\nboy"` to the relevant five-line string is trivial. *Making sure the result is valid markdown* is what's potentially hard. If markdown isn't really part of the question, you might want to remove it?

Comment: Hmm. If not an exact duplicate, this is very near to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656515/how-to-remove-double-quotes-in-jq-output-for-parsing-json-files-in-bash/44656583#44656583

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-r` argument to tell `jq` to use raw strings for its output.

```
jq -r . <<EOF
"I\nam\na\ngood\nboy"
EOF
```

...emits the precise output:

```
I
am
a
good
boy
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I'm also editing the question according to your suggestion.